# Node.js and Mongoose return 2D query

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, 2dsphere

I have a simple problem, I am trying to return a MongoDB document after a query in my Node.js server :

```
var coords = [];
        coords[0] = req.query.valArray.lng; // client latitude
        coords[1] = req.query.valArray.lat; // client longitude
        var distanceInKM = req.query.valArray.rangeKM; // the range 
         //the query that its results i want to return by res.send()
        db.Jobs.find( { 
            $and: [ { {exp: req.query.valArray.exp} }, 
                      { field: req.query.valArray.field } 
                  ] } )
```

My questions are:

1. How to return the document according to the `req.query` (exp = query.exp ) and the rest of the params by the `res.send()` function.
2. How to search by the coordination(coords) and the range from the current location `(lng , lat)`, in other words create a radius from the coords that all matching jobs will return as a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Your approach will not account for the curvature of the Earth so your calculations will be inaccurate if the distances are large.

I would advise to use [Geospatial Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) already supported by `MongoDB`.

**UPDATE**

For example you can use [`$centerSphere`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) operator which returns documents within a radius from a central point (example taken from there).

```
{
  <location field>: {
     $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ <x>, <y> ], <radius> ] }
     }
}
```

To do this you need to store your coordinates in [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) format (you need to add just a few meta fields to your html5 coordinates).

Comment: But you still didnt answer the question,  coords have html5 geolocation values, how to return values as a json from Mongo query?

Comment: Let me know if I need to write a more explicit example, though I think you can figure things out from here.